# Invalid Session: Proper Logout Behaviour

Tags: rest

In a REST API, when an invalid token is supplied for logout request, what is the most seen behaviour?

1. Should the client be notified of the invalid token?
2. Or should the API just respond with a success message?

I understand this is more of context specific, but just wanted to know what others think.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the nature of the 'invalidity' of the token and how much you want to involve the user in the interaction. Broadly speaking, I imagine you can have two different forms of invalidity.

- If it's malformed in some way, then you've basically got an invalid request which the user should be told about using a standard 4xx response code. Generally, this would imply either a bug in the client, but also possibly an active attack on your authentication / authorisation system. Given that the syntactic form of the token should not be a source of your security it's not really bad practice to inform the client that they *may* have a bug in their software.
- Another form of invalidity is that a valid token has expired - in this case, it's hardly important to tell the user that their current 'state' (effectively logged out because of expired token) is already their desired 'state' (logged out). The question here becomes one of avoiding triggering an automated token refresh on the client side. Use of a standard 2xx success code should avoid that.

Having said that, you *may* have a reason to want to inform the user that they're already logged out - say to let them know that any client-side state may be stale because the client has been unable to communicate with the server because of an invalid token. Ultimately, that's an application specific question.